# can't uninstall netbeans in ubuntu

Tags: netbeans, uninstallation, ubuntu-13.10

I am using `netbeans8.0` new version, i want to uninstall lower version `netbeans7.4` i tried using cmd like this in my terminal

```
root@selvaksa-OEM:/usr/local/netbeans-7.4# sh uninstall.sh
```

while executing this cmd i am getting error like below

```
Specified target component -nb-base/7.4.0.0.201310111528 
was not found in the registry. the Installer 
can continue as if the target component was not specified.
Click yes to continue, no to exit
```

if i click `yes`, it is asking to `uninstall` and then click `uninstall` to continue it is showing click `finish` to finish the IDE setup.

after click the `finish` nothing happens remains the same, pls help to find the solution to uninstall the

> netbeans7.4 IDE

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In order to properly uninstall Netbeans 7.4 you should delete the netbeans installation folder content, leaving just the principal folder. Reinstall the same version of netbeans that you had in that folder again and then run uninstall.sh. It worked for me.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Also worked for me uninstalling netbeans 8.2 with Fedora. Thanks !